# Determining if both variables are True or False

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function where two variables are in one `if` statement. followed by a(n) `== True`. It doesn't work, but here's what I tried in a better format.

```py
if var1, var2 == True:
 print("This function is correct")
else:
 print("This function doesn't work")
```

but it returned this message:

```
Invalid Syntax
```

Is there a way to make this function possible?

Comment: `var1 == True and var2 == True` or simply `var1 and var2`

Comment: `var1 == var2 == True`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can take advantage `var1` and `var2` are booleans, so:

```py
if var1 and var2:
    # your logic
```

Alternative, you can use the `all` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```py
if all([var1, var2]):
    # your logic
```

Note: you don't need to check equality for `True` in a conditional, the point is to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 2):

For determine if both statements are true you can use "and" logical operator.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

```
if var1 and var2:
 print("This function is correct")
else:
 print("This function doesn't work")
```

And, if you need to look whether it is true, you don't need to add `== True`.

Answer (score 2):

For a more general solution to testing if multiple variables are all `True`, you can use the `all` function instead of performing multiple `and` operations:

```
if all((var1, var2, var3, var4)):
    print("This function is correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find whether both of the variables are true or false in python you can simply type 'and' between the two arguments(variables) in your if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `all()`.
#Note: all takes only one argument, therefor we have to add `var1` and `var2` to a iterable.

```
var1,var2 = True,True
if all((var1, var2)):
    print('all true')
```

output

```
all true
```

Another option would be to use `.count()`.

```
var1,var2 = True,True
trues = [var1,var2]
if trues.count(trues[0]) == len(trues):
    print('all true')
```

Comment: if all((var1, var2)):